# Awesomium vb.net user agent

Tags: vb.net, youtube, awesomium

I am trying to open mobile version of youtube with awesomium on vb. Every time its redirect me to youtube.com desktop version.

```
    Private Sub youtube_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not WebCore.IsInitialized Then
        WebCore.Initialize(New WebConfig() With {.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"})
        WebControl1.Source = New Uri("m.youtube.com")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my code which i use at the moment but its not working. Any ideas how to access mobile version of youtube ?